# I am unable to save data from Android webview in mysql database

Tags: java, android, mysql, xml

I am accessing https://curj.000webhostapp.com/pmei_alumni/alumni_form.php through Android webview. I want to Save the form data into Mysql database. The problem is that by pressing the Save button it does not responded. It does not save the data into mysql.
Following is the code. Please help ..
Your Response would be Appreciable....

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.bilalkhawaja.pmeialumni.MainActivity">

<im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is the ManinActivity.JAVA Code**

```
package com.example.bilalkhawaja.pmeialumni;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
AdvancedWebView.Listener {

    String Url = 
"https://curj.000webhostapp.com/pmei_alumni/pmei_alumni.php";

    public AdvancedWebView mWebView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mWebView = (AdvancedWebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
mWebView.loadUrl(Url);
mWebView.setListener(this,this);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
mWebView.onResume();
// ...
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onPause() {
mWebView.onPause();
// ...
super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
mWebView.onDestroy();
// ...
super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
intent) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
mWebView.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        // ...
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (!mWebView.onBackPressed()) { return; }
// ...
        super.onBackPressed();
    }



@Override
public void onPageStarted(String url, Bitmap favicon) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(String url) {

    }

@Override
public void onPageError(int errorCode, String description, String 
failingUrl) {

    }

 @Override
 public void onDownloadRequested(String url, String suggestedFilename, 
String mimeType, long contentLength, String contentDisposition, String 
userAgent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onExternalPageRequest(String url) {

    }
    }

**AndroidManifest.xml code**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.bilalkhawaja.pmeialumni">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

[Html Form From which i am saving data into mysql database using Android Webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2lbX.jpg)

Comment: There is no code in your question that has anything to do with a button or any type of database, let alone one that you would access via a Web service (MySQL).

Comment: I have mentioned that i am using webview ..  i am saving data from web form through Android App Using Webview ..

Comment: There is no "Save" button on that form. Your form does not appear to work in a desktop Web browser either, possibly due to bugs related to a missing password confirmation field. Hence, it is unclear why you are considering this to be an Android issue, or even a MySQL issue, or what XML has to do with it (given the `xml` tag).

Comment: xml is used for the front end of the Android App ..
Open the given Link https://curj.000webhostapp.com/pmei_alumni/pmei_alumni.php 
Register yourself and then sign in you will get the above form ..

Comment: I want to Enter data from the given html form in android App using Webview as mentioned above ..

Comment: Data can be saved from html form through desktop browser but  the problem is that it does not save data when it is accessed in the Android App Using Webview .